# Ignore last part of URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have a FAQ page `/faq` (tab style) where every question should have its own 'ghost' url/page. So users could visit eg.

```
/faq/question-1
/faq/question-2
/faq/question-3
```

The problem is `question-1`, `question-2`, `question-3` are not actual pages but just sections on `/faq`. For SEO, aesthetics and usability reasons we do not want to work with ?q= or #

I've searched and tried every .htaccess thread I came across but without result.

Is there a way we can show the page`/faq` when visiting `/faq/question-1` and keep the url `/faq/question-1` with mod_rewrite? (we cannot hardcode it because we do not know all future question slugs) So basically something that tells the browser: if the first url part is /faq/, just ignore everything that comes behind but keep the url.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post samples of urls FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect/rewrite for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: Yes, you need to be explicit, what internal URL you want to rewrite this to. “Ignoring parts of URL” is not really a thing, so you will need to rewrite this to a different target URL internally. We don’t know your setup, so we can’t predict whether simply rewriting this to `/faq` will work, or if there might be more needed. We don’t know if this is a physical file, whether you removed a .php/.htm suffix via rewrite already, etc.

Comment: FROM `/faq/question-1`   (ideally something like /faq/*)
TO `/faq`
But the URL should stay faq/question-1 

@CBroe its in a CMS (Drupal) so there's already some redirection done 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial rewriting task and it is unclear why this should not work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?faq/.+ /faq [END]
```

Since you claim that you "tried every .htaccess thread you came across" and this clearly works the question is: why not in your setup? But since you did not tell us anything about your setup we cannot really offer more help...

These are some general hints though which you should go through:

- Where did you implement the rules you tried? In the http server's host configuration or in a distributed configuration file?
- If you are using a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") then how did you make sure such files are interpreted by your http server and how did you test that?
- Did you check your http server's error log file for hints?
- Did you make sure that you are not actually looking at cached responses? So did you really test with a fresh anonymous browser window using a "deep reload"?
- Since the CMS you are using requires own rewriting rules, where did you add those rules you tried? Remember: the order is important!